# how to prove this inequality $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2+(u-1)^2+(w-1)^2+(2v+1)^2\ge 4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers, and such $$(a+c)(b+d)=\sqrt{2}(ac-2bd-1)$$
show that
$$(ab-1)^2+(bc-1)^2+(cd-1)^2+(da-1)^2+(ac-1)^2+(2bd+1)^2\ge 4$$

My try: let $x=ab,y=bc,z=cd,w=da,u=ac,v=bd$,then  have
$$x+y+z+w=\sqrt{2}u-2\sqrt{2}v-\sqrt{2}$$ we must prove
$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2+(u-1)^2+(w-1)^2+(2v+1)^2\ge 4$$

But I use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$[(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2+(u-1)^2+(w-1)^2+(2v+1)^2][1+1+1+2+1+2]\ge (x-1+y-1+z-1+w-1+\sqrt{2}u-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}v+\sqrt{2})^2=(4+\sqrt{2})^2$$
so we have
$$(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2+(u-1)^2+(w-1)^2+(2v+1)^2\ge\dfrac{(4+\sqrt{2})^2}{8}=\dfrac{9+4\sqrt{2}}{4}$$
and I can't prove the inequality left  hand  side is big than $4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}(ab-1)^2+(2bd+1)^2+(ac-1)^2=$$
$$=6+\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2-2(a+c)(b+d)+a^2c^2-2ac+4b^2d^2+4bd=$$
$$=5-2(a+c)(b+d)+\sum_{cyc}a^2b^2+4abcd+(ac-2bd-1)^2=$$
$$=(ab+cd)^2+(bc+ad)^2+\frac{1}{2}(a+c)^2(b+d)^2+5-2(a+c)(b+d)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}((a+c)(b+d)+2)^2+(ab+cd)^2+(bc+ad)^2-4(a+c)(b+d)+3=$$
$$=(ab+cd-2)^2+(bc+ad-2)^2+\frac{1}{2}((a+c)(b+d)+2)^2-5=$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}(1+1+2)((ab+cd-2)^2+(bc+ad-2)^2+\frac{1}{2}((a+c)(b+d)+2)^2)-5\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{4}\left(-ab-cd+2-bc-ad+2+(a+c)(b+d)+2\right)^2-5=4.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $(ac-1)^2 + (2bd+1)^2 = (ac - 2bd-1)^2 + 4abcd + 1 = \frac{(a+c)^2(b+d)^2}{2} + 4abcd + 1$,
the inequality becomes
$$(ab-1)^2+(bc-1)^2+(cd-1)^2+(ad-1)^2 + \frac{(a+c)^2(b+d)^2}{2} + 4abcd + 1 \ge 4$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2}(pa^2 + qa + r) \ge 0$$
where
\begin{align}
p &= 3 b^2+2 b d+3 d^2, \\
q &= 2 b^2 c+12 b c d+2 c d^2-4 b-4 d, \\
r &= 3 b^2 c^2+2 b c^2 d+3 c^2 d^2-4 b c-4 c d+2.
\end{align}
Clearly $p \ge 0$.
Also, $r = (bc - cd)^2 + 2(bc + cd)^2 - 4(bc + cd) + 2 = (bc - cd)^2 + 2(bc + cd - 1)^2 \ge 0$,
and $4pr - q^2 = 8(b-d)^2(2bc+2cd-1)^2 \ge 0$. We are done.